# How to create an array of given values from a file?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a file `input.txt` like:

```
n
a1 a3 a3 an
```

where `n` is quantity of elements(array size), and `a1` `a2` `a3` `an` are the elements.

How can I create an array of `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `an` objects?
I tried to do this using example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line) question, but as I understand I can't create array in the loop as it will create it on every iteration.

Comment: Start with the knowledge that C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) or other dynamic arrays. It *does* have [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) though. Then think about where you need to declare this vector for it to be available both inside the loop *and* after the loop is done, and without being "recreated" inside the loop.

Comment: (1) read the first line and convert the string to an integer. (2) declare or allocate an array (or other suitable data structure) of length `n` (given in (1)). (3) read the next line of the file and parse out `n` elements (you haven't mentioned their types so I leave *parse* definition to you). If this isn't helpful, then I think you need to do some C++ tutorials to get grounded in the basics of the language. You could do an internet search on "C++ read data from file" for example.

Comment: As `n` is known in advance, one dynamic allocation also does the trick. But I'm sure you don't have heavy performance requirements, so just stick to `vector` and perhaps use `reserve`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create a `vector`, something like this:

```
ifstream fin("inout.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
int n;
fin >> n;
vector<int> v;
int m;
while (n--) {
    fin >> m;
    v.push_back(m);
}
```

Then you can always get an array from

```
int *array = v.data();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `an` are integers like

```
4
1 2 3 4
```

An example implementation:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    int *a;
    FILE* fp;

    // read the text and create an array
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) return 1;
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &n) != 1) return 1;
    a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[i]) != 1) return 1;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    // print the array for checking
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d\n", a[i]);

    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> but as I understand I can't create array in the loop as it will create it on every iteration.

You're correct.

If you don't want to create a new array on every iteration, then don't create the array *in* the loop. Create it *outside* the loop.